# small sh script to log processes ram and cpu usage

Tags: linux, bash, sh

i have the following sh script, on a centos machine:

```
echo "PID,CPU,MEM,PROC"
while [ 1 ]
do
    ps aux | grep mysql | awk '{print  $2",", $3",", $4",", $11}'
    sleep 1
done
```

the output every cycle has this output:

```
1163, 0.0, 0.0, /bin/sh
1265, 0.0, 1.5, /usr/libexec/mysqld
11807, 0.0, 0.3, grep
```

I wonder how to cycle the outputs and use variables to merge the value and return just one line: i don't need PID and PROC in the merged result

```
mysql, 0.0, 1.8
```

where 0.0 is CPU (all processes cpu usage sum) and 1.8 RAM (all processes ram usage sum).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ps -eo "comm %cpu %mem" --no-headers | awk '{a[$1] = $1; b[$1] += $2; c[$1] += $3}END{for (i in a)printf "%s, %0.1f, %0.1f\n", a[i], b[i], c[i]}' | sort
```

Example output:

```
awk, 0.0, 0.0
bash, 0.0, 1.5
ps, 0.0, 0.0
sort, 0.0, 0.0
```

Process specific:

```
ps -C bash -o "comm %cpu %mem" --no-headers | awk '{a[$1] = $1; b[$1] += $2; c[$1] += $3}END{for (i in a)printf "%s, %0.1f, %0.1f\n", a[i], b[i], c[i]}'
```

Output:

```
bash, 0.0, 1.5
```

Comment: i dosen't match the request, sorry i wasn't clear. if i replace with mysql it dosen't count mysqld, i need something to aggregate usages of matching processing. for exmaple the httpd has severals processes, i want to sum them all to reach the final amout of apache

Comment: @TrustWeb I made an update. I think it should work now as intended. Please check.